# UITableView add subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, addsubview

I want to add subview in `UITableView`

I tried like this way:

```
[self.tableView addSubView:myView.view];
```

I didn't got any error but view is not getting added, can anyone please help..?

Thanks.

Comment: if myView is of type UIView then just [self.tableView addSubView:myView];

Comment: what is myView? is it subclass of UIViewController or UIView

Comment: i had created object of UIView and added in subview of tableview

Comment: then you should write like this ...[self.tableView addSubView:myView]

Comment: i had added in my comments that i had already successfully accomplished my task still thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, -view.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
[self.tableView addSubview:view];
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(view.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0)];
```

this will add the view above the cells and move the cells down by the height of the added view.

Answer (score 2):

I am no getting why you are adding subview to Tableview. May be you want to add something to each cell of tableView. You can do this by adding:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourSubView];
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
}
```

Comment: now its working fine actually i had to add indicator in the middle of the tableview with transparent view at background but now its working fine thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Both of `self.tableView` and `myView` should not be `nil`

What do you mean `myView.view`?

this piece of code works good for me:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 200, 20)];
labelView.text = @"TEST";
[headerView addSubview:labelView];

[self.tableView addSubview:headerView];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:

```
let foregroundView = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height))
foregroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
tableView.addSubview(foregroundView)
foregroundView.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)
```

You can remove it also:

```
foregroundView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply replace your line of code with the one below:**

```
[self.tableView.superview addSubview:myView];
```

**Note:**

I am not certain about `myView.view` in line of code you mentioned in your question.

Comment: tableView.superview  is nil